# C++ TensorRT batch inference gives weird results

Tags: c++, machine-learning, inference, tensorrt

Good day everyone!

I have a problem performing batch inference in TensorRT. When the batch size is 1 it works like a charm, but when I change it to any other number it gives out plain garbage.

Step by step, I downloaded TensorRT (5.0) and installed it on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop with GTX755M. I then built the samples that went with it and tested it on sampleMNIST sample and it worked like a charm. I then proceeded to change every occurrence of `mParams.batchSize` to 10. Of course I also changed the size of allocated memory and modified result printing along. But after I recompiled the sample I got completely weird results - the output says 80% 7 20% 1 for every given input:

```
grim@shigoto:~/tensorrt/bin$ ./sample_mnist
Building and running a GPU inference engine for MNIST

Input:

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@.*@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@.=@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@+@@@.=@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@% #@@.=@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@% #@@.=@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@+ *@@:-@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@= *@@= @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@. #@@= @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@=  =++.-@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@       =@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@  :*## =@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@:*@@@% =@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@% =@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@# =@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@# =@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@* *@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@= #@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@= #@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@=.@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@++@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

Output:

0: 
1: ********
2: 
3: 
4: 
5: 
6: 
7: **
8: 
9:
```

This output repeats 10 times. I've tried this with different networks but results were similar, most of networks give 1 correct output and plain garbage the other 9 times. The complete sample can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/GrimMaple/f64693887452a9c659d3e48a0161098a). I've tried googling documentation but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong or how to perform batch inference in TensorRT?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also modified the `mnist.prototxt`?

Especially this part:

```
input: "data"
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 1
  dim: 28
  dim: 28
}
```

I think that should be:

```
input: "data"
input_shape {
  dim: 10
  dim: 1
  dim: 28
  dim: 28
}
```